# Was the acronym BIOS (computing) intentional re: the Ancient Greek βίος?

Tags: terminology

I ask because other acronyms could certainly have been chosen, but BIOS has a specific meaning in Ancient Greek, which, along with Latin, are the source languages of much of our scientific terminology.

[βίος : life (Autenrieth)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0073%3Aentry%3Dbi%2Fos1)

See also [βίος (Liddell/Scott)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dbi%2Fos1)

*This word is the root of modern words like biology.*

The acronym was apparently created by [Gary Kildall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Kildall), and I'm wondering if he, or anyone who was working with him, has commented on this.

Comment: Do you mean BIOS as in the computing term? Do you have any reason to think there is some connection? Also, I'm not sure this is the best site for this question; it's more about computing, or language, than it is about "history".

Comment: @IMSoP absolutely I think there is a connection, and that the choice of that specific combinations of letters was intentional.  But, sans commentary from the coiner, it can only be speculation.  Tradition of Greek terminology aside, there is a strong analogy at play.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I really don't see the connection. There's nothing "lifelike" about a system for abstracting basic input and output, and the acronym "BIOS" seems so natural that there's really no reason to look for an additional meaning.

Comment: @IMSoP I have to strongly disagree on that count.  I'd say it's definitely *analogous* to a biological system, even if the mechanics differ.  (On this count, we're in the area of philosophy, but here I'm asking about allusions re: a fundamental science acronym.)

Comment: BIOS could be apronym, this is not unusual as it helps with memorizing certain terms.

Comment: What about the BIOS (particularly in its original meaning) is more analagous to a biological system than any other computer program? [According to Wikipedia, CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M#Components_of_the_operating_system), which originated the term, had three main components named BIOS, BDOS, and CCP; other systems would call the I/O abstraction a "HAL" ("Hardware Abstraction Layer"). Only later did "BIOS" come to refer to the wider functionality of motherboard-hosted firmware.

Comment: @rs.29 I'd tend to agree.  It's pretty impossible for anyone with a basic knowledge of Greek, even if that knowledge is restricted to scientific terminology, not to make the βίος connection.  There is also a history of playful naming in science (quarks as a famous example.)

Comment: @DukeZhou Note that CP/M was not a science / research effort, it was a personal and then commercial project. It's about as related to "quarks" as it is to "CBS".

Comment: @IMSoP The field of computing may primarily an engineering field, but my sense is it still falls under the umbrella of science.  *(Quarks was only mentioned as the most famous example of playful naminhg--there are a fair amount of polymaths in science.)*

Answer (score 3):

I think it's very unlikely that there was an explicit connection intended, beyond making the acronym pronounceable.

[Wikipedia includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) various accounts of the origin of the term, which all agree that the original requirement was for an abstraction layer to handle input and output (frequently abbreviated as I/O) in order to release CP/M on a variety of hardware platforms. This concept is more generally known as a Hardware Abstraction Layer, or HAL, but since the discussions were all about I/O, the name "Basic I/O System" seems to have just been the obvious choice. The fact that other components of the system have acronyms which don't remotely resemble Greek words suggests that there was no culture of clever references in the CP/M team at the time.

Only later did the term come to refer to the more complex firmware that controls a PC's boot system, which I suspect is what you are thinking of as "analagous to a biological system" (although I still don't see the connection myself). At this point, it was just an earlier term being borrowed and applied to a new technology with some of the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I may not agree, but I appreciate you contributing! (My sense is that there would have been an awareness of the Greek meaning, and, while it's entirely possible this was just a coincidence, but even so, I'm confident there would have been awareness of the allusion and implication that might be drawn.  Specifically, another acronym could have been chose to *avoid* this allusion.)

Comment: @DukeZhou I totally understand the "awareness" part, but I still have no idea what the allusion would be. If the letters spelled the Greek word for "coincidence" it would be no more or less relevant to the task.

Comment: My only comment would be that, after nearly half a century of usage, it does seem that BIOS is the only logical choice, but I'd caution you that idea may be a fallacy.  The choice of those 4 letter is that order may even have been a factor in that acronym becoming the adopted, standard term.

Comment: @DukeZhou In 15 years, Wikipedia has never been able to find proof of the connection between BIOS and the Greek word: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Talk:BIOS&oldid=313220391#BIOS_as_'life'_in_Greek%3F

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks for linking.  To my mind, the fact that a debate has been going on for years makes this a legit Stack question!

Comment: @DukeZhou True, I'm just saying that there may not be a better answer out there. The truth may really be that people associated with the Greek after the fact or that the original coiner was subconsciously influenced by the Greek word, but we may never know.

Comment: @DukeZhou Also, note that Timwi (the user who submitted the alleged factoid to Wikipedia in the first place) says that it is plausible to them but not certain, i.e. speculation.

Comment: @called2voyage OK, thanks to that link, I finally understand the supposed allusion that nobody was actually explaining, in the reference to "linking soul and body". I still think it's highly tenuous, unless anyone has evidence that Gary Kildall or Glenn Ewing was into metaphysics.

Comment: @DukeZhou I've certainly argued the opposite in the past - e.g. "Simultaneous Peripheral Operation On Line" is such awkward wording that the acronym must surely be contrived; but "Basic Input/Output System" reads as a perfectly straightforward name, in line with other acronyms like "Basic Disk Operating System", so there seems no reason to invoke extra meaning, except as a cute coincidence after the fact.